# How to remove page number from the title page

Tags: header-footer, numbering, titles, page-numbering

I am using the following solution to insert page number:

```
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{centered page number}
{%
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertpagenumber\,/\,\insertpresentationendpage%
  \hspace*{\fill}\vskip2pt%
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[centered page number]
```

But, I want to remove the page number from the title page.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see an entire example document so we know how you're creating the title page and what other relevant settings you have, but from what I can tell with a fairly typical setup the usual way of suppressing the page number works, i.e.:

```
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{frame}
```